# zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync()

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am new with the unit test of angular and i am using jest, I install it with ng add @briebug/jest-schematic.
When run npm test (jest) in a base project throws the next error

```
FAIL  src/app/app.component.spec.ts (7.418 s)
  AppComponent
    ✕ should create the app (6 ms)

  ● AppComponent › should create the app

    zone-testing.js is needed for the fakeAsync() test helper but could not be found.
            Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/testing

      at resetFakeAsyncZone (../packages/core/testing/src/fake_async.ts:25:9)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../packages/core/testing/src/test_hooks.ts:39:7)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:387:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:408:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:261:3)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.579 s
```

How to resolve this problem, thanks
and here is the app component.spec

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });



});
```